# c# propertygrid with custom typeconverter, can't enter string

Tags: c#, propertygrid, typeconverter

i have a class Measurement that can be either in inches or millimeters, now using the expandabletypeconverter its a bit annoying changing the measurement, so i wanted to create a custom one. the problem is, the propertygrid seems to ignore it. i put break points but nothing is ever called. here is the code:

```cs
[TypeConverter(typeof(MeasurementConverter))]
public class Measurement
{
    double mm;
    public bool IsMM
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public double Inches
    {
        get { return mm / 25.4; }
        set { mm = value * 25.4; IsMM = false; }
    }
    public double Millimeters
    {
        get { return mm; }
        set { mm = value; IsMM = true; }
    }

    public Measurement(double value = 0, bool ismm = true)
    {
        if(ismm)
        {
            Millimeters = value;
        }
        else
        {
            Inches = value;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if(IsMM)
        {
            return Millimeters.ToString(SVGElement.doubleFormat) + "mm";
        }
        else
        {
            return Inches.ToString(SVGElement.doubleFormat) + "in";
        }
    }
}

public class MeasurementConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return typeof(string) == destinationType;
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if(destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            Measurement m = value as Measurement;
            return m.ToString();
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return typeof(string) == sourceType;
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        string str = value as string;
        if(str != null)
        {
            var tmp = context.Instance;
            Measurement m = new Measurement();
            if(str.EndsWith("mm"))
            {
                m.Millimeters = double.Parse(str.Substring(0, str.Length - 2));
            }
            else if(str.EndsWith("in"))
            {
                m.Inches = double.Parse(str.Substring(0, str.Length - 2));
            }
            else //assume mm
            {
                try
                {
                    m.Millimeters = double.Parse(str);
                }
                catch { }
            }
            return m;
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

i cant enter a string in the propertygrid. it just shows what toString() returns.

Answer (score 0):

im a dingus and still had a typeconverter attribute on the properties themselfes in the class that was containing them.